# Unable to click on button in rediff.com website at user login page

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Unable to click on button after entering the email address.

```
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("http://in.rediff.com/");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='homewrapper']/div[5]/a[3]/div/u")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='wrapper']/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='useremail']")).sendKeys("xyz");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='emailsubmit']")).click();
```

I am supposed to see the password input box after the submit button click. For somereason I am not able to see this. Am I doing anything wrong? Not getting any errors after this line.

```
    System.out.println("Finish");
```

This line is executed as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is clicking on the Submit button perfectly.

As per the rediff functionality, if "xyz"(username) you are entering doesnt exist, then it will redirect to Login form.

So the reason you are not getting password object. Try with any existing user account(username).

Comment: this works on Firefox without any issue. I have the latest chrome and chrome driver installed. When I change the chromedriver version to 2.12, the issue is gone. there is some issue with chromedriver version 1.13